# Why do I get an error when create a function but not when a variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, strict, referenceerror

Could you please explain why following code gives me an error (in strict mode only)?

```js
'use strict';


name = 'Adam';
console.log(name);

doSomething = function() {};
```

CONSOLE:

Adam

ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode, specifically https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strict mode forbids implicit globals.

Variables must be explicitly declared (with `const`, `let`, or `var`).

You can create an explicit global by assigning a property to the global object (`window` in a browser)… but don't: Globals are a good way to get conflicts between different parts of code. (e.g. between the browser built-in [`name` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) and your own `name` variable).

Comment: @SlawomirJakubek — Because it is already declared (see the third paragraph of this answer).